# Is it possible to color-code a Matplotlib Imshow figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm working with some 2D data, in this case, a speech spectrogram, and I'd like to mark the speech diarization in-figure if possible. I've very quickly mocked up a nice way to visually indicate the diarization by using a color-coding schema per column at the top. One could imagine that such color-coding should also lead to having a matplotlib.legend() object on the side.

To generate the labelling, I would like to use a 1-D vector of class labels (e.g. [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, etc.] for all columns).

It would be cool if the legend also made use of [qualitative colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html).

[image]

So in short, is there any way to natively do this in Matplotlib?

Comment: Yes, just put another imshow in a subplot or axes on top.

Comment: ... Or just add a line or rectangle in axes co-ordinates in y, and data co-ordinates in x using a blended transform:  https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html#blended-transformations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To flesh out [@ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest)'s comment, here is how I would go about doing what you are looking for:

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
# use of `make_axes_locatable` simplifies positioning the
# accessory axes

# Generate data, it would have been nice if you had provided
# these in your question BTW
Ncols, Nlines = 200,50
data = np.random.random(size=(Nlines,Ncols))
class_labels = np.zeros(shape=(Ncols,))
class_labels[50:100] = 1
class_labels[100:150] = 2
class_labels = class_labels.reshape((1,Ncols))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
# create new axes on the right and on the top of the current axes.
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
class_ax = divider.append_axes("top", size=0.1, pad=0., sharex=ax)
cbar_ax = divider.append_axes("right", size=0.1, pad=0.1)

#plot sonogram
im = ax.imshow(data, cmap='viridis')
fig.colorbar(im, cax=cbar_ax) # sonogram colorbar

# plot diarization classes
class_ax.imshow(class_labels, aspect='auto', cmap='rainbow')
class_ax.set_axis_off()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for coding this out! I had not at all known about the `make_axes_locatable` utility function. Great to know!